# I want to display error message using javascript.this code is correct or not? alerts are working

Tags: jquery

```
 $(document).on('click','.f',function(){
        alert('Happy New Year');
       var status1 = $('.b').val();
       alert('status'+status1);
                    if(status1=='open') {
                        alert('status'+status1);   
                            $('.b').text("Status Field Should not be Open");
                        }
                    });
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save1}" styleClass="f"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!a.Status__c}"  styleClass="b"/>
```

Comment: Which is your component having class `.b`

Comment: <apex:inputField value="{!a.Status__c}"  styleClass="b"/>

Comment: Please share your relevant code in question using  [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/245404/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cancel the event in order to prevent the page from calling the save function.

```
if(status1=='open') {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('Status field should not be open.');
}
```

Note that JavaScript is case-sensitive; you may have meant `Open` instead of `open`.

Comment: i want error message not alert message...

Comment: I want error message using jquery when the record is save